# Convert Reader to String

Tags: java, json, clob, reader

Am using `java.io.Reader` class to Read the **CLOB** content from DataBase. Am trying to convert the content to `String` using `IOUtils` class

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(reader);
```

And my string would be a json and converting it to java object

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();

JSONdata jsonData;
jsonData=gson.fromJson(json, JSONdata.class);
```

Here toString methods gives the empty value since it didn't convert to string. I have worked with inputstream and it works. I need reader class to be converted to string.

Comment: The bug is probably in the code you're not showing. Show us the code used to get the reader. Make sure the CLOB is not empty in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a CLOB, use the getAsciiStream or getCharacterStream method of an java.sql.CLOB object to retrieve the entire CLOB as an input stream. The getAsciiStream method returns an ASCII input stream in a java.io.InputStream object. The getCharacterStream method returns a Unicode input stream in a java.io.Reader object. So To get your content in UTF-8 use getCharacterStream and use it with reader. It will work